# Как при записи в csv добавить в конец пустой елемент?

Tags: python, файлы, csv

Есть функция которая сохраняет данные в csv

```
def csv_writer(data, path):
    with open(path, 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        spamwriter.writerow(data)
```

Все обрабатываеться корректно. Но при загрузке файла на сайт парсер сайта не видит последнеюю ячейкую. Если открыть файл в Notepad то видно что все ячейки разделены `;` , а последний элемент не имеет точки с запятой. Как добавить точку с запятой в последнюю ячейку?

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("your_csv_file.csv", 'a') as f:
    f.write(';')
```